I want update logo and when user chat to bot in every chat update logo and title in dialogflow bot
I want update logo and when user chat to bot in every chat update logo and title in dialogflow bot This is my bot like this image
I have read out the official documentation for CSS customization of this chat widget but I couldn't found any useful method to handle this issue.
I want update logo and when user chat to bot in every chat update logo and title in dialogflow bot

Didn't the documentation help?
